# Why mind is all set to achieve something unknown during meditation?

Tags: meditation-hindrances

Sitting in front of the rising sun, observing atmosphere and self. Mostly all of come to me in a very unexpected way. Yes, it is easy to achieve what he and a few of holy them have achieved. Is it not a kind of craving?

Comment: http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/18002/where-did-the-hindrances-originate-from

Comment: What do you mean by its easy to achieve what he ( Buddha ) achieved ...just seems that you might be generalising the entire doctrine ...

Comment: I meant to say that living a life the way he showed to us is much easier and happier than the one which we are living as whole, now a days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it not a kind of craving?"

If you're asking whether a craving for enlightenment is a kind of craving, I think the answer is "yes".

That kind of craving is mentioned e.g. in the [Bhikkhuni Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.159.than.html):

> This body comes into being through craving. And yet it is by relying on craving that craving is to be abandoned.

And in the [Brahmana Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn51/sn51.015.than.html):

> Brahman, there is the case where a monk develops the base of power endowed with concentration founded on desire & the fabrications of exertion. He develops the base of power endowed with concentration founded on persistence... concentration founded on intent... concentration founded on discrimination & the fabrications of exertion. This, Brahman, is the path, this is the practice for the abandoning of that desire."
>
> "If that's so, Master Ananda, then it's an endless path, and not one with an end, for it's impossible that one could abandon desire by means of desire.
>
> etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is [craving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%E1%B9%87h%C4%81) and [intention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chanda_(Buddhism)). Enlightened people had intention but not craving to achieve their goal which is what you should aim to develop. Craving for the goal also will set you back.